# Does main method work differently in enums and classes?

Tags: java, oop, enums, static, program-entry-point

In the following code :

```
enum Rank {
    FIRST(20), SECOND(0), THIRD(8);
    Rank(int value) {
        System.out.print(value);
    } 

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" " + Rank.values().length);
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
2008 3
```

If however the `main` method is declared in some other class like this:

```
class XYZ {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\n" + Rank.values().length);
    }
}
```

The output is only `3`.
What is the difference between `main` in enum and `main` in the class? Why do I have two different outputs?

Comment: There is no difference in the enum and other class. It's just a difference in the fact that the code there is run when the class is loaded. a bit the same as if you had a static block in XYZ and added a print statement there.

Comment: Are you sure your first code snippet is correct with the opening and closing curly braces?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. I got the output `2008 3` when I used the external class. I also commented out he `main` method in the `Rank` but still the same output

Comment: Enum instances are `public static final`. If you added equivalent fields and a ctor to `XYZ`, it would do the same, because static fields are initialized by the classloader when the class is first used.

Answer (score 4):

Enum constants are `static`. They are initialized on class initialization (an `enum` is just a class). This means when you call `main` of a class that references the `enum` type, all values are created using the constructor.

If the other class does not reference the `enum` in any way, then no output would be printed because no `enum` is evaluated.

Comment: could not reproduce your problem. I got the output `2008 3` when I used the external class. I also commented out he main method in the `Rank` but still the same output

Answer (score 2):

Most significant difference between a class and enum is that ENUM has its instances predefined. The value is being printed while the enum loads it executes the constructor for Enum in order to create ranks which in turn prints its value. while executing main for normal class has no method implementation and no creation of objects automatically. You have to create instances of the class.Hope you got my point.

Further details on [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

So no difference in main method but difference is visible to you because instances for enum are created when the enum is loaded by VM. :)

As per @Blip's request I am updating my answer, So even if you separate out main method it won't change a thing. As the main method still referring the Rank enum,hence the Enum is being loaded by the runtime and as we already know that instances of Enums will be created at the time of loading the class it will still execute the constructor and hence you will see the output as 2008 3

Comment: could not reproduce your problem. I got the output `2008 3` when I used the external class. I also commented out he main method in the `Rank` but still the same output

Comment: @Blip It's not about separation of the main method, it's about when the instances of the Enum are being created. See thats the most significant difference between enum and class. The instance creation for enum is taken care by JVM when it loads that particular enum. so Even if you separate out that main method you will still get 2008 3 as output but try removing Rank from the System.out.println statement. further more refer the link that I have provided for enum will give some basic idea about difference :) :) hope it helps

Comment: I checked and found it correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I would request you to change your answer so as to correct this point of difference that has been mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually seeing the constructor for the enum printing.

So at the start `Rank.FIRST` is created and `System.out.print(value);` is called with 20.

Then the same thing happens with `Rank.SECOND` and `Rank.THIRD`; this is all done by the class loader because the Rank enum is being used by `EnumCreation`.

Since the constructor in `Rank` uses `print` and not `println` they all show up on 1 line.

Then when `EnumCreation` enters the main method it prints a space followed by `Rank.values().length` and a newline.

When `XYZ` enters the main method it should do the same thing; but it would print a newline instead of the space.

From a class standpoint though, you have 3 classes. Rank, EnumCreation, and XYZ. Rank and EnumCreation just happen to share 1 *.java file.

Hope that helps clear things up!

Comment: It looks like the main method in both classes in the question was edited to remove the `System.out.println()` statement. Due to that change `EnumCreation` would still cause 2008 to print when it runs since the class loader would load `Rank` in the same file during runtime, causing all 3 enum values to be statically constructed. And since `XYZ` now has no references to the `Rank` class at all or any instructions in its main method anymore, it will not do anything.

Comment: could not reproduce your problem. I got the output `2008 3` when I used the external class. I also commented out he main method in the `Rank` but still the same output

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a `Class` initializer and an instance (or `Object`) initializer.  `Class` initializers are run when the `Class` is loaded, which usually happens the first time it is referenced.  `Object` initializers are constructors which are run only when a new instance is created with the `new` keyword (barring reflection).

`Enum`s are static instances.  You can think of them kind of like singletons -- you never `new` an `Enum`.

So let's say I have this `Class` definition

```
public class Foo {
    static{
        System.out.println("Someone loaded the class");
    }

    public Foo(){
        System.out.print("Foo constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Making Foo");
        Foo foo = new Foo();

    }
}
```

The output is

```
Someone loaded the class
Making Foo
Foo constructor
```

`Enum` will work like the static block in `Foo`.

Here's an `Enum` example

```
public enum FooValues {
    HELLO,GOODBYE,WHAT;

    private FooValues(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main");
    }
}
```

This gives

```
HELLO
GOODBYE
WHAT
in main
```

Because when the `Enum` is loaded, *all* values are initialized during the class loading phase, and then the `main` method is run.

Comment: could not reproduce your problem. I got the output `2008 3` when I used the external class. I also commented out he main method in the `Rank` but still the same output

Comment: @Blip Pretty sure your comment was directed at the OP, yes?  Might want to delete it from my answer and put it on the OP's question.

Comment: No it is directed also towards you so that you could correct the answer to this scenario Also I have made this comment on all the posts of this question as appropriate action can be taken by individuals.